# Display users on Linux with tabbed output

Tags: linux, shell

I am working with Linux and I am trying to display and count the users on the system. I am currently using who -q, which gives me a count and the users but I am trying not to list one person more than once with it. At the same time I would like the output of users on separate lines as well or tabbed better than it currently is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will show the number of unique users logged in, ignoring the number of times they are each logged in individually:

```
who | awk '{ print $1; }' | sort -u | awk '{print $1; u++} END{ print "users: " u}'
```

If the output of `who | awk '{ print $1 }'` is :

```
joe
bunty
will
sally
will
bunty
```

Then the one-liner will output:

```
bunty
joe
sally
will
users: 4
```

Previous answers have involved `uniq` (but this command only removes duplicates if they are storted, which who does not guarantee, hence we use `sort -u` to achieve the same.

The awk command at the end outputs the results whilst counting the number of unique users and outputtig this value at the end.

Comment: whats odd is when I run the command above it formats the same way you have above. But when I make a script using a variable for it, it puts it all on one line. Any ideas?

Comment: @StevenEck if you are doing `foo=$( command above )` ensure that you print it using `echo "$foo"` using the double quotes around the variable, otherwise the newlines will get lost.

Comment: @imp25 +1 Much improved from my answer.  I particularly like the use of awk for displaying the total.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
who | awk '{print $1}' | uniq && who -q | grep "\# " | cut -d' ' -f2
```